# GitLab CI/CD: Trigger pipeline when anything is changed less three files

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline in Gitlab CI/CD and I want it to be triggered when anything is changed but it should ignore three files and also the tags.
My except section looks something like that:

```
except:
    - tags
    - "**/packages/**/package.json"
    - packages/plugins/st/package.json
```

The issue is that the pipeline is triggered also when packages/plugins/st/package.json, for example, is changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `changes`keyword in your except: (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges)

```
except:
  refs:
    - tags
  changes:
    - **/packages/**/package.json
    - packages/plugins/st/package.json
```